# Drop box control by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, dropdown

I have few questions in my HTML code and each question has sub questions for ranking. Ranking selection is drop down list and is ranking from 1-3.

I want to validate that the same rank has not been used multiple times in the same question. Here is my HTML:

```html
<div>
  <span id="questionnaire-question">Q1)&nbspPlease QuestionA</span>
  <table>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>A1</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[13]" class="02A" group="02A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>A2</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[14]" class="02A" group="02A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>A3</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[15]" class="02A" group="02A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>A4</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[16]" class="02A" group="02A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="questionnaire-question">Q2)&nbspPlease QuestionB</span>
  <table>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>B1</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[21]" class="03A" group="03A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>B2</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[22]" class="03A" group="03A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>B3</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[23]" class="03A" group="03A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 365px;">
      <td>
        <label>B4</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="ranking[28]" class="03A" group="03A">
          <option value="">Please Rank</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Specify your question. What is the problem? What do you want to do?

Comment: you want to make sure A1 is not same as B1, and A2 not as B2 etc.. right?

Comment: Are you expecting one sub question to be left unselected, as you have 4 questions with only 3 options...? Also note that your non-breaking spaces are missing a semi colon at the end. They should be `&nbsp;`

Comment: Okay, In Question 1, there are A1,A2,A3 and A4, i want to make sure they dont have the same ranking

Comment: hi @kelvinfoo have you tested my answer? also one note,, your html is not correct,, you have same ID's for both questions,, just for fyi: ID's have to be unique and classes can be same

Comment: @kelvinfoo can you see my answer and give a comment please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code,, I have made only to alert the user that it needs to select new value,, but you can do whatever you need..

```
// event when select change
$('select').on('change', function(evt){
    // parent table, one question ref
    var Q = $(this).closest('table');
    // iterate all answers to have diff res
    for(var i = 0; i < $(Q).find('select').length; i++ ){
        // console.log( parseInt($(Q).find('select').eq( i ).val()) )
        if( parseInt( $(Q).find('select').eq( i ).val() ) && 
           !$(Q).find('select').eq( i ).is( $(this) ) &&
           $(Q).find('select').eq( i ).val() == $(this).val() ){
             alert ('Choose another Rank please!');
            $(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);
        }
    }
})
```

See live example here: http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/RKpLwX?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks oserk, this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `jquery` or `javascript` .I have done using `jquery`.Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spr3ume9/1/).